# Informix SQL query with a join on a date in a certain range

Tags: sql, informix

I have put together a query that gets me a bunch of data from a couple of tables but I need to bring in a labour price where the `effective_date` in the labourates table is the `max(labourates.effective_date)` that is less than or equal the `labourline.alloc_entry_date`

The join is on `labourline.alloc_entry_date` and `labourline.part_code` (both of which are in the `labourates` table)

I have tried a bunch of outer join options but i'm not real good at the current join methodology (im from the days of `*=`)

Current query is this:

```
Select  'Labour' part_type,
    labourline.order_num,
    ordhead.order_date,
    labourhead.alloc_entry_date,
    labourline.part_code,
    product.desc_text,
    ordhead.cust_code,
    product.cat_code,
    product.prodgrp_code,
    product.maingrp_code,
    product.ware_code,
    0 unit_rate_amt,
    labourline.order_qty,
    labourline.uom_code,
    product.weight_qty,
    product.cubic_qty,
    product.area_qty,
    product.length_qty
from    ordhead,
    labourline,
    labourhead,
    product
where   labourline.cmpy_code = 'EC'
and product.cmpy_code = 'EC'
and ordhead.cmpy_code = 'EC'
and labourhead.cmpy_code = 'EC'
and labourline.part_code = product.part_code
and labourline.order_num = ordhead.order_num
and labourline.order_num = labourhead.order_num
and ordhead.order_date >= MDY(08,01,2018)
and ordhead.order_date < MDY(08,01,2019)
```

This code gets me the `unit_rate_amt` i need when given a `PartCode` and a `CheckDate`

```
Select   unit_rate_amt
from    labourates
where   part_code = 'PartCode'
and effective_date = (
        select max(effective_date) from labourates
        where part_code = 'PartCode'
        and effective_date <= 'CheckDate'
    )
```

Merging it into the initial query to replace `0 unit_rate_amt,` is proving to be something that I can't work out.

Comment: Are you using Informix 12.10 or some other version?  It might matter; it might not.  It's always a good idea to say what you are using, though.  Also, please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses;
MCVE was good for over five years and it did not need changing).
In an SQL question, that means a minimal set of tables, and an outline schema of each of those tables, and preferably some sample data, and the desired output from the sample data.

Comment: It's not clear that you're going to need outer joins, let alone Oracle-style outer joins, which are possibly even weirder then Informix-style outer joins, though the competition is high!

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use what I call TDQD — Test-Driven Query Design.  I build up a complex query step by step.  You've given me a huge flying start with your main query and the sub-query that needs to be integrated into the main query.  Your developing the standalone sub-query is exactly the sort of thing that TDQD encourages.

When asking questions on SO, please ensure you minimize the number of fields in things like queries.  For example, the four items `product.weight_qty`, `product.cubic_qty`, `product.area_qty`, `product.length_qty` are undoubtedly all important in your 'real life' query, but they really don't affect us on SO.  One of those is plenty here; maybe even that is overkill since you've selected `desc_text` from `product`.

It is also important to provide an outline schema of the tables — my TDQD is not test driven because you did not supply usable, minimal table schemas, let alone sample data to process and the expected output.  You'll get better answers to your question if your question is easier to answer because you've supplied that information.

As a general rule of thumb, in the current millennium, you should not use the `FROM table1, table2, table3, …` notation in SQL any more.  You should use JOIN explicitly.

#### Step 1 — Simplification of main query and use of JOIN

Taking your main query, I revamped it like this:

```
SELECT 'Labour' AS part_type,
       ll.order_num,
       oh.order_date,
       lh.alloc_entry_date,
       ll.part_code,
       pr.desc_text,
       oh.cust_code,
       0 unit_rate_amt,
       ll.order_qty,
       ll.uom_code,
       pr.length_qty
  FROM ordhead    AS oh
  JOIN labourline AS ll ON oh.order_num = ll.order_num AND oh.cmpy_code = ll.cmpy_code
  JOIN labourhead AS lh ON lh.order_num = ll.order_num AND lh.cmpy_code = ll.cmpy_code
  JOIN product    AS pr ON pr.part_code = ll.part_code AND pr.cmpy_code = pr.cmpy_code
 WHERE ll.cmpy_code = 'EC'
   AND pr.cmpy_code = 'EC'
   AND oh.cmpy_code = 'EC'
   AND lh.cmpy_code = 'EC'
   AND oh.order_date >= MDY(08,01,2018)
   AND oh.order_date < MDY(08,01,2019)
```

I use `AS` to introduce abbreviations for tables.  I often use single-letter abbreviations; here, double-letter ones seemed more appropriate.  I eliminated a number of elements from the select-list portion as not sufficiently material to your question.

I inferred from your repeated use of `xyz.cmpy_code = 'EC'` that the tables could be joined with `cmpy_code` as part of the join condition; I use that in the `ON` conditions for the joins.  I also inferred that `labourline` is the central table in this query and listed it first.  The other tables join to it, rather than to each other.  I left the repeated conditions like `AND pr.cmpy_code = 'EC'` in the query, but I'd probably eliminate all except `ll.cmpy_code = 'EC'` unless the query plans showed a significant benefit from keeping the constant terms.

#### Step 2 — Integrate sub-query

This requires some interpretation of your 'working sub-query'.  I assume that what you refer to as `CheckDate` is the `labourline.alloc_entry_date`, and the part code is the `labourline.part_code`.  With the JOIN notation, it is easy to slide the sub-query into the main query, like this:

```
SELECT 'Labour' AS part_type,
       ll.order_num,
       oh.order_date,
       lh.alloc_entry_date,
       ll.part_code,
       pr.desc_text,
       oh.cust_code,
       lr.unit_rate_amt,
       ll.order_qty,
       ll.uom_code,
       pr.length_qty
  FROM labourline AS ll
  JOIN ordhead    AS oh ON oh.order_num = ll.order_num AND oh.cmpy_code = ll.cmpy_code
  JOIN labourhead AS lh ON lh.order_num = ll.order_num AND lh.cmpy_code = ll.cmpy_code
  JOIN product    AS pr ON pr.part_code = ll.part_code AND pr.cmpy_code = ll.cmpy_code
  JOIN (SELECT lr1.part_code, lr1.unit_rate_amt AS unit_rate_amt
          FROM labourates AS lr1
         WHERE lr1.part_code = ll.part_code
           AND lr1.effective_date =
               (SELECT MAX(effective_date)
                  FROM labourates AS lr2
                 WHERE lr2.part_code =  ll.part_code
                   AND lr2.effective_date <= ll.alloca_entry_date
               )
       )          AS lr ON lr.part_code = ll.part_code
 WHERE ll.cmpy_code = 'EC'
   AND oh.order_date >= MDY(08,01,2018)
   AND oh.order_date < MDY(08,01,2019)
```

That is a correlated sub-query because of the references to `ll.part_code` and `ll.alloc_entry_date` in the sub-query.  I suspect that there would be ways of converting that from a correlated sub-query into a non-correlated sub-query.  Certainly, if/when that causes problems with slow response times, that's the first place I'd be looking for improvements.  The `ll.alloc_entry_date` value is crucial to the sub-query, though, and so correlation may be unavoidable.  If the correlation is unavoidable, then ensuring that there are appropriate indexes in place also becomes crucial.  Even the main query, with the joins on `cmpy_code` and other columns, will benefit from the appropriate indexes being available.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, Those join constructs you made actually make sense to me, I have been meaning to learn this for a while so thanks :). With the sub query I am getting an error: `Column (alloc_entry_date) not found in any table in the query` I commented that line out for testing then got the same error for part_code. Is it possible that the sub-query can't reference tables outside of itself? It seems to not be able to reference `ll`

Comment: I'm glad the 'lesson in JOIN notation' is useful. It generally makes life easier, I find. I converted shortly after SO started up  Regarding the sub-query, I was expecting it to be a correlated sub-query that would use the value of `ll`. Apparently, I'm wrong. Can you do me a favour (on the way to me doing you a favour) and send some (preferably close to minimal) SQL that would create the tables — see my profile for my email address. Also, please include details of the version number of Informix you're using. (`SELECT DBINFO('version','full') FROM systables WHERE tabid = 1` would work.)

Answer (score 0):

For completeness I managed to get this working. It creates dupes somewhere and I can't figure out where but distincting it works:

```
Select  distinct 'Labour' part_type,
    ll.order_num,
    oh.order_date,
    lh.alloc_entry_date,
    ll.part_code,
    pr.desc_text,
    oh.cust_code,
    oh.sale_code,
    pr.cat_code,
    pr.prodgrp_code,
    pr.maingrp_code,
    pr.ware_code,
    lr1.unit_rate_amt,
    ll.order_qty,
    ll.uom_code,
    pr.weight_qty,
    pr.cubic_qty,
    pr.area_qty,
    pr.length_qty
from    labourline AS ll
JOIN    ordhead    AS oh ON oh.order_num = ll.order_num AND oh.cmpy_code = ll.cmpy_code
JOIN    labourhead AS lh ON lh.order_num = ll.order_num AND lh.cmpy_code = ll.cmpy_code
JOIN    product    AS pr ON pr.part_code = ll.part_code AND pr.cmpy_code = ll.cmpy_code
JOIN    labourates    AS lr1 ON lr1.part_code = ll.part_code AND lr1.cmpy_code = ll.cmpy_code
where   ll.cmpy_code = 'EC'
and oh.order_date >= MDY(08,01,2017)
and oh.order_date < MDY(08,01,2018)
and lr1.effective_date = 
    (
    SELECT  MAX(effective_date)
    FROM    labourates lr2
    WHERE   lr2.part_code =  ll.part_code
    AND lr2.effective_date <= lh.alloc_entry_date
    AND lr2.ware_code = ll.ware_code
    )
```

Thanks @Jonathan Leffler for teaching me the join construct.